# Study of a complex function (2)

Tags: complex-analysis, meromorphic-functions

> Consider the function $f(z)=(4z^2+1)\tanh (\pi z)$. Determine its singularities, and, in particular, the residues in the poles.

This first part should be easy: the singularities of $\tanh (\pi z)$ are in the points $\{\frac i 2 +ik:k\in \mathbb Z \}$, and they are all simple poles since the hyperbolic tangent has period equal to $\pi i$ and$$\lim _{z\to \frac i 2}\frac {e^{2\pi z}-1} {e^{2\pi z}+1}=\frac {-2}{2\pi z}=-\frac 1 {\pi z}\ .$$ However $4z^2+1$ has simple zeros in $\frac i 2$ and $-\frac i 2$, so in the end the singularities of $f$ are in $\{\frac i 2 +ik:k\in \mathbb Z, k \ne 0,-1 \}$; they are simple poles with residues $\frac {4k^2+4k} \pi$, for the corresponding $k$, because $4(\frac i 2 + ik)^2+1=-(4k^2+4k)$.

> Then the exercise asks to prove that, if a function $g$ is holomorphic at infinity, then $g(z)$ is the sum of a series of the form $\sum_{j=0}^\infty a_jz^{-j} $, when $|z|$ is large enough.

I reasoned in this way: if $g(z)$ is holomorphic at infinity, it means that $G(z)=g(\frac 1 z)$ is holomorphic in $0$. So in any $z_0$ near $0$ we can write $G(z)=G(z_0)+G'(z_0)(z-z_0)+\dots$ , or equivalently $g(\frac 1 {z})=g(\frac 1 {z_0})+g'(\frac 1 {z_0})\frac 1 t+\dots$ , where $t=\frac 1 {z-z_0}$. As $z\to z_0$, $t$ should approach $\frac 1 {z_0}$, however I don't feel like this proof is correct. Can you help me with this?

> Finally, the exercise asks to (1) calculate $\int_{D_R(0)} f(z)dz$, where $D_R(0)$ is the disk centered in $0$ with radius $R$, when $R$ is large enough; and (2), to study how $\frac {f(z)} {z^3}$ behaves at infinity.

Now, I thought that to calculate the integral, I could just calculate (using residues theorem) $$2 i \sum_{k=1}^\infty(4k^2+4k)+ 2i \sum _{k=2}^\infty (4k^2-4k)=16i+2i \sum _{k=2}^\infty 8k^2\ .$$ However this doesn't seem to have much sense to me, because as $R$ goes to infinty it doesn't converge; so, it's very likely that I'm wrong somewhere, even if I don't see where. For what regards point (2), it should be immediate that the point at infinity is an essential singularity for $\frac {f(z)} {z^3}$, because otherwise it would be meromorphic on the whole Riemann sphere; however $\frac {f(z)} {z^3}$ is not rational, and this is a contradiction. Thank you in advance for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Consider the function $f(z)=(4z^2+1) \tanh(\pi z)$. Determine its singularities, and, in particular, the residues in the poles.

I think your argument for the singularities of $f(z)$ is mostly correct (as in, I think what you're *trying* to say is correct), however precisely what you've written doesn't quite make sense. Note that your limit
$$\lim_{z \to \frac{i}{2}} \frac{e^{2 \pi z}-1}{e^{2 \pi z}+1}$$
does not exist, and the RHS of your equality contains $z$, despite taking $\lim_{z \to \frac{1}{2}}$. However, you're computing virtually the correct thing, that is,
$$\tanh (\pi z) = \frac{1}{\pi} \left(z - \frac{i}{2}\right)^{-1} + \dots$$
near $z = \frac{i}{2}$, which has its pole cancelled by the corresponding simple zero of $4z^2+1$.

Personally, my preferred argument here would be that $\cosh \pi z$ has simple roots, so $\tanh \pi z$ has simple poles at $z_k = i \left( \frac{1}{2} + k\right)$ for $k \in \mathbb{Z}$, with those at $z_0$ and $z_{-1}$ cancelled by the simple zeros of $4z^2+1$. For the remaining $z_k$,
\begin{align*}
\operatorname{res}\left(f(z), z_k \right) &= \lim_{z \to z_k} (z-z_k) f(z) \\
&= (4z_k^2+1) \sinh (\pi z_k) \cdot\lim_{z \to z_k} \frac{z-z_k}{\cosh \pi z_k} \\
&= (4z_k^2+1) \sinh (\pi z_k) \cdot \lim_{z \to z_k} \frac{1}{\pi \sinh \pi z_k} \\
&= \frac{4z_k^2+1}{\pi} = \frac{4k(k+1)}{\pi}
\end{align*}
where we applied L'Hôpital to deduce the value of the limit (which also shows we do indeed have removable singularities at $z_0$ and $z_{-1}$).

> Then the exercise asks to prove that, if a function $g$ is holomorphic at infinity, then $g(z)$ is the sum of a series of the form $\sum_{j=0}^\infty a_jz^{-j} $, when $|z|$ is large enough.

I'm going to state that [holomorphic means analytic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analyticity_of_holomorphic_functions) and the result essentially falls out immediately. It's entirely possible that this distinction hasn't even been noted to you, and often these terms get used interchangeably.

If $g$ is holomorphic at infinity, then it is holomorphic at $u \equiv \frac{1}{z} = 0$, and so analytic in some disc $\lvert u \rvert < \frac{1}{R}$. Then, within this disc, we can expand it as a Taylor series about $u= 0$,
$$g|_u = \sum_{j=0}^\infty a_j u^j$$
Translating this back to $z$, we have that for $\lvert z \rvert > R$,
$$g(z) = \sum_{j=0}^\infty a_j z^{-j}$$

> Finally, the exercise asks to (1) calculate $\int_{D_R(0)} f(z)dz$, where $D_R(0)$ is the disk centered in $0$ with radius $R$, when $R$ is large enough; and (2), to study how $\frac {f(z)} {z^3}$ behaves at infinity.

For $R$ sufficiently large (note not in the limit $R \to \infty$, however), say with $N < R < N + 1$ for some $N \in \mathbb{N}$, we use the residue theorem. Recall there are poles for $k \in \mathbb{Z} \setminus \lbrace 0, -1 \rbrace$, so we have
$$I = \int_{D_R(0)} f(z) \; dz = 2 \pi i \sum_{k = -N}^N \frac{4k(k+1)}{\pi}$$
where we've included the sum over $k = 0, -1$ since these terms do not contribute.
Noting that
$$\sum_{k=-N}^N k = 0, \quad \sum_{k=1}^N k^2 = \frac{N(N+1)(2N+1)}{6}$$
we can simplify $I$ to
$$I = 8i \sum_{k=-N}^N k^2 = 16 i \sum_{k=1}^N k^2 = \frac{8i}{3} \cdot N(N+1)(2N+1)$$
For the behaviour of $f(z) z^{-3}$ as $z \to \infty$ - well, this is somewhat more subjective of a question. The leading order behaviour (due to the $4z^2+1)$ is going to be given by studying
$$g(z) = \frac{4 \tanh(\pi z)}{z}$$
It should be clear that this is not holomorphic at $\infty$, since there are infinitely many poles - at each $z_k$ - and we have $\lvert z_k \rvert = k + \frac{1}{2} \to \infty$.

Moreover, if we consider $u = z^{-1}$, then we see that the singularities accumulate at $0$, i.e. every region $\lvert u \rvert < \delta \ll 1$ contains a countably infinite number of poles. That is, $u = 0$ is *not* an isolated singularity.